# turtlesim_node wont start on MAC OSX 10.6

Tags: ros, rosmake, turtlesim, turtlesim-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im trying to start with ROS, so im following the tutorials, my problem comes when I want to launch turtlesim_node by using the command rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node. It says:

[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named turtlesim_node below /Users/ME/ros/ros_tutorials/turtlesim

Then i try:
rosmake turtlesim and i got these errors:

"wxBitmap::wxBitmap(int, int, int)", referenced from:
turtlesim::TurtleFrame::TurtleFrame(wxWindow*)in turtle_frame.o
"_wxDefaultPosition", referenced from:
turtlesim::TurtleFrame::TurtleFrame(wxWindow*)in turtle_frame.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [../bin/turtlesim_node] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/turtlesim_node.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2

any idea what could be wrong?
thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10026/turtlesim_node-wont-start-on-mac-osx-10.6/) by [Sergio Omar](https://answers.ros.org/users/577/sergio-omar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just built the diamondback ros_tutorials stack [from source](http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/OSX) on a OS X 10.6.7 machine, and had no trouble compiling, linking, or running turtlesim/turtlesim_node.  It works fine for me.  Looks like you have a problem with your wx installation.  Suggestions:

- Make sure you have wx (and other supporting libraries) installed:

```
    rosmake --rosdep-install ros_tutorials
```

- Reinstall wx:

```
    sudo port deactivate wxWidgets-python
    sudo port uninstall wxWidgets-python
    sudo port install wxWidgets-python
```

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3